# Migrating into custom node type with multi value field

Tags: 8, migrations, plugins

I'm doing a migration into D8, and I'm migrating into a custom video player field with multiple values. Here's the schema for the field as defined in its plugin:

```
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return array(
      'columns' => array(
        'vid' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'size' => 'normal',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'default' => 0,
        ),
        'video' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'video_hd' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'video_sm' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'thumbnail' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'poster' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
        'show_ads' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'size' => 'tiny',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'default' => '1',
        ),
        'raw_file' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 256,
          'not null' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have a custom source plugin that gathers all of the information needed for these columns into appropriately named items. My question is, how do I get those pieces of data into the destination field. Can I do it in the .yml file configuration, as can be done with the body field?

```
  'body/format':
    plugin: migration
    migration: d6_filter_format
    source: format
  'body/value': node_body
  'body/summary': teaser
```

Or do I need to have a custom destination plugin that takes these pieces of data and puts them into the correct places in the node? I'm seeing a lot of blogs and documentation on source and process plugins, but not much on destination plugins, so I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with destination plugins, what you need to do would be in the process pipeline. You could write a custom process plugin like, say, d6_cck_link. Or, you can use the iterator process plugin - see, for example, how d6_upload.yml in core populates the target_id/display/description columns of the 'upload' field.

Comment: So I'm looking at d6_cck_link plugin (aka the CckLink class), and I see that it returns a $route array. Am I reading correctly that that array are the column values for the field, equivalent to the definitions in the schema definition in my question?

Comment: Yep - you'll return an array with 'vid', 'video', 'video_hd' etc. keys.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, trying that but it isn't working (see [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222818/destination-fields-not-filled-from-custom-migration-process-plugin)).